# Detecting duplicate entries

Tags: r, string, filter

I'm trying to write a function to detect if two names in a table are similar. Let's say an entry is duplicated, but written differently: the following examples illustrate the situation

```
Ned Flanders and Nedd Flanders
Ned F and Ned F.
Ned Flanders and Nedd Flanders
Ned Flanders and Ned Flamders
```

I thought of creating a function that would be able to detect if two names have most of the characters the same, which occurs in the cases illustrated above. The problem is that a very long name can contain all the characters of a smaller name, even though the names are very different.

Any way to resolve this? You don't need to detect with 100% accuracy, it would be just an extra way to ensure that there is no duplication.

I know that the table should have a unique key, but at the moment this is not possible and considering other columns in the filter does not work because in some cases there are changes in the other columns as well.

```
duplicity_detect <- function(vec) {
  duplicity<-data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2))
  colnames(duplicity)<-c('name','nome similar')
  for (i in 1:(length(vec)-1)){
    for (j in (i+1):length(vec)){
      x<-strsplit(gsub(x = vec[i],pattern = " ",replacement = ""),split = "")[[1]]
      y<-strsplit(gsub(x = vec[j],pattern = " ",replacement = ""),split = "")[[1]]

      intersec <- x[x %in% intersect(x, y)]
      if (length(intersec)>0.99*length(x) | length(intersec)>0.99*length(y)){
        duplicity[nrow(duplicity) + 1,] = c(vec[i],vec[j])
      }
    }
  }
  return(duplicity)
}
```

**EDIT:**

I rewrote the function following the idea of ​​@Shan R

```
duplicity_detect <- function(vec) {
  duplicity  <- lapply(vec, FUN = agrep, vec, value = T)
  duplicity  <- duplicity[lapply(duplicity, length) > 1]
  return(duplicity)
}
```

Comment: try agrep, approximate matching. agrep(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, value = FALSE,
      max.distance = 0.1)

Comment: What type of table are you reading from? Does the function need to read from the table or just check for similarity?

Comment: you can consider a data.frame, the idea is to filter a column that contains the names

Comment: In fact I would like to get a new data.frame with similar names so that I can decide if it is a duplicate entry or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seem to do okay. It recognizes John Doe is not a match and knows John Doe and Jcob are different:

```
x <- c("Ned Flanders","Ned F", "Ned F.", "Ned Flamders", "John Doe", "Jacob Boyun")

y <- lapply(x, FUN = agrep, x, value = T)
unique(y[(lapply(y,length) > 1)])
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Ned Flanders" "Ned Flamders"

[[2]]
[1] "Ned Flanders" "Ned F"        "Ned F."       "Ned Flamders"
```

Comment: tested it here and apparently it worked fine. Is there a way to filter this list and collect only the names in which another similar one was detected?

Comment: Any entry with length > 1 has a similar one. Will try to update the code.

Comment: I edited my question by adding a new function, I still need to check more details, but it seems to be working very well

Comment: I updated the solution to filter the list. Since this works for you, consider "accepting" the solution by clicking the grey checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you're looking for in text-mining is *cosine similarity*.  It works with very long documents (book length) and with short ones (individual words).

I can't vouch for it personally, but look at the `textmineR` package.  Vignette is here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textmineR/vignettes/b_document_clustering.html

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Pythons **difflib** package and import [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher).
This class compairs sequences of any type as long as it's hashable.
 **.ratio()** returns a measure of the sequences similarity as a float between 0.0 and 1.0

1.0 would prove to be identical.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def check_similarity(col_a, col_b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, col_a, col_b).ratio()


print(check_similarity('Ned Flanders', 'Nedd Flanders'))

print(check_similarity('Neds Flanders', 'Nedd Flanders'))

print(check_similarity('Ned Flanders', 'Ned Flanders'))
```